# Decode UTF-8 from JSON file

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have a JSON file with a encoded UTF-8 string field that represents a JPG content:

```json
"ImageData": "ÿØÿà\u0000\u0010JFIF\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0000\u0000d\u0000d\u0000\u0000
```

I am parsing the JSON and getting that value:

```pascal
var imageString : string;
...
imageString:=jv.GetValue<string>('ImageData');
```

But I am having issues while decoding the bytes and save them to a file

Option 1. `SaveBytesToFile(BytesOf(imageString),pathFile);`

As you can see, the header is not correct (should start with ÿØÿà)

[image: option1]

Option 2. `SaveBytesToFile(TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imageString),pathFile);`

Similar issue as option 1

[image: option2]

Code for SaveBytesToFile:

```pascal
procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
var
  stream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    if length(data) > 0 then
      stream.WriteBuffer(data[0], length(data));
    stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

How I can decode it properly?

Comment: Fix the JSON is the right solution

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JSON is a text-only format, it has no provisions for handling binary data at all.  Why are the image bytes not being encoded in a text-compatible format, like [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64), [base85](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii85#RFC_1924_version), [base91](http://base91.sourceforge.net/), etc?  Otherwise, use something like [BSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BSON) (Binary JSON) or [UBJSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBJSON) (Universal Binary JSON) instead, which both support binary data.

In any case, `BytesOf()` will corrupt bytes, since it uses the user's default locale (via `TEncoding.Default`, which is UTF-8 on non-Windows platforms!), so characters outside of the ASCII range are subject to locale interpretation and won't produce the bytes you need.

In your situation, make sure the JSON library is decoding the JSON file as UTF-8, then you can simply loop through the resulting string (the JSON library should be parsing the escaped sequences into characters for you) and truncate the characters *as-is* to 8-bit values. Don't perform any kind of charset conversion at all.  For example:

```
var
  imageString : string;
  imageBytes: TBytes;
  i: Integer;
  ...
begin
  ...

  imageString := jv.GetValue<string>('ImageData');

  SetLength(imageBytes, Length(imageString));
  for i := 0 to Length(imageString)-1 do begin
    imageBytes[i] := Byte(imageString[i+1]);
  end;

  SaveBytesToFile(imageBytes, pathFile);

  ...
end;
```

[image]

On a side note, your `SaveBytesToFile()` can be greatly simplified without wasting memory making a copy of the `TBytes`:

```
procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
var
  stream: TBytesStream;
begin
  stream := TBytesStream.Create(Data);
  try
    stream.SaveToFile(FileName);
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
var
  stream: TFileStream;
begin
  stream := TFileStream.Create(FileName, fmCreate);
  try
    stream.WriteBuffer(PByte(Data)^, Length(Data));
  finally
    stream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Or:

```
uses
  ..., System.IOUtils;

procedure SaveBytesToFile(const Data: TBytes; const FileName: string);
begin
  System.IOUtils.TFile.WriteAllBytes(FileName, Data);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, I don't have control over the generated JSON so I need to work with it. I have implemented your suggested code but I get the same results BTW, I have noticed that after reading the value from the json, there is already some data loss https://www.screencast.com/t/C1Rx57gt

Comment: That "data loss" in that screenshot is actually just raw UTF-8 byte octets being stored as-is as string characters. What version of Delphi are you using, and which JSON library are you using? Are you telling the library to decode the JSON file as UTF-8? If not, you should be. If you are, it should not be outputting raw UTF-8 octets as string characters, unless maybe you were using Delphi 2007 or earlier. But in Delphi 2009, where `string` is `UnicodeString`, raw UTF-8 octets should not be output into a Unicode string.

Comment: I was missing to read the JSON as UTF-8 with TEncoding.UTF8. Thanks.

Comment: Analogous to Base64, where a certain set of characters encodes binary values, I call this Base256. It's more compact than Base64 but can only be used when 256 different characters are supported. Often the encoding is the reverse of ISO 8859-1. (Even when expressed formally like that, I still don't like it.)

Answer (score 0):

`C3 BF C3 98 C3 BF C3 A0` are the correct bytes for the UTF-8 string `ÿØÿà`, I'd say your Option 1 conversion works.

Don't be fooled by your hex editor : the UTF-8 chars `ÿØÿà` all fall outside of the  ASCII range, but hex editors generally display e-ASCII chars for each single byte, which is why it displays `Ã¿` instead of `ÿ`.

Do check the locale issue mentioned by @RemyLebeau, <strike>I think using TEncoding.ASCII would be the correct one</strike>.

Comment: `TEncoding.ASCII` is 7bit and will lose data for bytes > $7F